# Finding largest sum in an unsorted array using divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I have a sequence of n real numbers stored in a array, A[1], A[2], …, A[n]. I am trying to implement a divide and conquer algorithm to find two numbers A[i] and A[j], where i < j, such that A[i] ≤ A[j] and their sum is the largest.

For eg. {2, 5, 9, 3, -2, 7} will give the output of 14 (5+9, not 16=9+7). Can anyone suggest me some ideas on how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also what language are you aiming to do this in. This is a three liner in python :)

Comment: What makes you think "divide and conquer" is the right approach?

Comment: what is the expected complexity? O(nlgn)?

Comment: Also what is the answer of {5,4,3,2,1} ?

Comment: posting it here for posterity http://jsbin.com/cameci/5/edit?js,console but I'm not too happy of it, and not sure about the complexity

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not really suited to a divide and conquer approach.
 It's easy to observe that if (i, j) is a solution for this problem, then A[j] >= A[k] for every k > j, i.e A[j] is the maximum in A[j..n]

Prove: if there exists such k > j and A[k] > A[j], then (j, k) is a better solution than (i, j)

So we only need to consider `j`s that satisfies that criteria.

Algorithm (pseudo-code)

```
maxj = n
for (j = n - 1 down to 1):
  if (a[j] > a[maxj]) then:
    maxj = j
  else:
    check if (j, maxj) is a better solution
```

Complexity: O(n)
C++ implementation: http://ideone.com/ENp5WR (The implementation use an integer array, but it should be the same for floats)

Comment: where does the j comes from in a loop of i?

Comment: Then it is proved to be correct now I think, though it is not D&C as asked in OP, still upvoted for a clean solution

Answer (score 0):

Declare two variables, during your algorithm check if the current number is bigger than either of the two values currently be stored in the variables, if yes replace the smallest, if not, continue.

Comment: How is this a "divide and conquer" algorithm?

Comment: it breaks an array of numbers down into a simple what number is bigger

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution in Python. I wouldn't exactly call it "divide and conquer" but then again, this problem isn't very suited to a divide and conquer approach.

```
def recurse(lst, pair):             # the remaining list left to process
    if not lst: return              # if lst is empty, return
    for i in lst[1:]:               # for each elements in lst starting from index 1
        curr_sum = lst[0] + i   
        if lst[0] < i and curr_sum > pair[0]+pair[1]:  # if the first value is less than the second and curr_sum is greater than the max sum so far
            pair[0] = lst[0]
            pair[1] =  i        # update pair to contain the new pair of values that give the max sum
    recurse(lst[1:], pair)          # recurse on the sub list from index 1 to the end 

def find_pair(s):
    if len(s) < 2: return s[0]
    pair = [s[0],s[1]]      # initialises pair array
    recurse(s, pair)    # passed by reference
    return pair
```

Sample output:

```
s = [2, 5, 9, 3, -2, 7]
find_pair(s)     #       ============> (5,9)
```

Comment: What will your algo produce for {1,7,5,6}?

Comment: @serhiyb It produces [5,6]. You can try it [here](https://repl.it/D4sB).

Comment: you should initialize with [-Infinity, -Infinity], and it's O(n²)

Comment: Yeah I see, but your complexity is O(n^2) while author is looking for O(n*log(n)) - typical divide&conquer complexity.

Comment: @serhiyb This is not a problem suited for a divide and conquer approach. You can't force a problem to conform to divide and conquer strategies; it needs to have some sort of self similarity. This is the closest I can think of.

Comment: Im not saying that this problem fits d&q well but I'm saying that O(n^2) is not best asymptotic complexity for that problem.

Comment: also you don't need the fake recursion, just 2 nested loops

Comment: @caub I'm not saying this is an approach I would use. I'm saying this is the most "d&q" approach I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use an algorithm in `O(n)` as described follow

(The merge part uses constant time)

Here is the outline of the algorithm:

1. Divide the problem into two half: LHS & RHS
2. Each half should returned the largest answer meeting the requirement in that half **AND** the largest element in that half
3. Merge and return the answer to upper level: answer is the maximum of LHS's answer, RHS's answer, and the sum of the largest element in both half (consider this only if RHS's largest element >= LHS's largest element)

---

Here is the demonstration of the algorithm using your example: {2, 5, 9, 3, -2, 7}

1. Divide into {2,5,9}, {3,-2,7}
2. Divide into {2,5}, {9}, {3,-2}, {7}
3. {2,5} return max(2,5, 5+2) = 7, largest element = 5
4. {9} return 9, largest element = 9
5. {3,-2} return max(3,-2) = 3, largest element = 3
6. {7} return 7, largest element = 7
7. {2,5,9} merged from {2,5} & {9}: return max(7,9,9+5) = 14, largest element = max(9,5) = 9
8. {3,-2,7} merged from {3,-2} & {7}: return max(3,7,7+3) = 10, largest element = max(7,3) = 7
9. {2,5,9,3,-2,7} merged from {2,5,9} and {3,-2,7}: return max(14,10) = 14, largest element = max(9,7) = 9

ans = 14

---

Special cases like {5,4,3,2,1} which yields no answer needs extra handling but not affecting the core part and the complexity of the algorithm.